# Qt 4 - QProcess problems

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtgui, qapplication

I'm trying to compile a Qt 4 Application which contains the call of QProcess.

It's no problem to compile it as Release-Version, but I always get a SegmentionFault-Error when i execute the Debug-Version.

My Qt version is 4.8.2 and i tried it on Fedora and Debian OS.

Does anyone of you ever had similar problems?
I can't figure it out!

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>

class MyApplication : public QApplication{
public:
    QProcess * proc;
    MyApplication(int argc, char** argv) : QApplication(argc, argv){
        proc = new QProcess();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Have a nice day, 
Markus

Comment: thanks for the reply, here is what gdb shows me:
http://pastebin.com/A0pREW1S

Comment: hmmm, when i comment out the qprocess-stuff it makes no problem. 
the mainwindow is pretty empty, just did a simple new qt-gui-application
http://pastebin.com/dm5NwniH

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yABLvmaQ
thats the header.

Comment: QMainWindow doesn't work neither :/

Comment: your snippet also works just in Release Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash is caused by this line:

```
MyApplication(int argc, char **argv);
```

You should modify it to:

```
MyApplication(int &argc, char **argv);
```

The reason is that, without reference, there is a temporary copy included which basically gets destroyed, while the address of it is still stored. The crash happens at the access afterwards.

See the warning [in the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#QCoreApplication) of the `QApplication` constructor:

> Warning: The data referred to by argc and argv must stay valid for the entire lifetime of the QCoreApplication object. In addition, argc must be greater than zero and argv must contain at least one valid character string.

That being said, it is probably not worth subclassing `QApplication` in your case. Even if you do, make sure you do not leak the memory by not deleting the heap object created for handling the background process with `QProcess`.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping!
any idea why it just breaks in Debug-Mode?

Comment: @m.schmidinger It's called undefined behavior. Be thankful it didn't launch a nuclear strike :)